# Resizing a 3D image (and resampling)

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library, nipy

I have 3D image of a brain (let's call it flash) and it's currently 263 x 256 x 185. I want to resize it to be the size of another image(call it whole_brain_bravo); 256 x 256 x 176, and (hopefully) use a lanczos interpolation to resample (Image.ANTIALIAS). My (failed) attempt:

```
from scipy import ndimage as nd
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np



a = nib.load('flash.hdr') # nib is what I use to load the images
b = nib.load('whole_brain_bravo.hdr')

flash = a.get_data() # Access data as array (in this case memmap)
whole = b.get_data()

downed = nd.interpolation.zoom(flash, zoom=b.shape) # This obviously doesn't work
```

Have you guys ever done this sort of thing on a 3D image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docstring for `scipy.ndimage.interpolate.zoom`:

```
"""
zoom : float or sequence, optional
    The zoom factor along the axes. If a float, `zoom` is the same for each
    axis. If a sequence, `zoom` should contain one value for each axis.
"""
```

What is the scale factor between the two images? Is it constant across all axes (i.e. are you scaling isometrically)? In that case `zoom` should be a single float value. Otherwise it should be a sequence of floats, one per axis.

For example, *if the physical dimensions of `whole` and `flash` can be assumed to be equal*, then you could do something like this:

```
 dsfactor = [w/float(f) for w,f in zip(whole.shape, flash.shape)]
 downed = nd.interpolation.zoom(flash, zoom=dsfactor)
```

Comment: This is actually good thanks. Would you also know how to resample downed by any chance?

Comment: That's what `np.interpolation.zoom` does to produce `downed` from `flash`! You can change the order of the spline interpolation it uses via the `order=` parameter (I'm not aware of any implementation of Lanczos interpolation in numpy/scipy).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I was hoping I could use Lanczos. It isn't that big of a deal though. And yes lanczos is implemented in the python imaging library; Image.ANTIALIAS is actually a 3-lobe lanczos written in C (according to the documentation)

Comment: As I'm sure you're already aware, PIL only handles 2D images, so you would be limited to resampling 2D slices of your array. I honestly don't think you'd see much practical difference between Lanczos and cubic spline interpolation anyway.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, the `zoom` argument is "The zoom factor along the axes".  That's a little vague, but it sounds like they mean a scale factor, rather than the desired dimension.

Try this:

```
zoomFactors = [bi/float(ai) for ai, bi in zip(a, b)]
downed = nd.interpolation.zoom(flash, zoom=zoomFactors)
```

Not sure about choosing a filter - the docs only mention spline interpolations of various orders.

Comment: How would you go about resampling a 3D image in python in general? Like say I give you an image, and you look at it and go "oh this looks crap, I should probably do some nearest neighbour to make it a little nicer", how would you do it?

Comment: In what sense would downsampling an image ever make it look *nicer*?  If I wanted to resample an array, I guess I would try using scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.  Is that not working for you?  I'm sure there are plenty of ways to do it, but unless you describe why this one isn't good enough, I can't help ya.

Comment: It's not that it isn't good enough, I just really like the results that lanczos scheme has when downsampling, say, a jpeg so I wanted to maybe reproduce it in a 3d image. But it isn't a big deal, spline is fine (hehe I rhymed). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'll look around, but I don't know of a way to use the Lanczos filter for 3D resampling off the top of my head - good luck!

Comment: @elefun , would interpolation.zoom with order=0 not work for nearest-neighbor downsampling?